# Adding an extra variable to a column in django-tables2

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-tables2

Trying to build a Django (1.4) site that has some pages that can be either loaded in a popup or not. Some of these pages contain a listview, implemented in [Django-tables2](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-tables2)

When a page is loaded as a popup, an extra URL parameter is added; for example
`/backoffice/popup/articlegroups/` is the same page as `/backoffice/articlegroups/` , but shown as a popup.

My question is how to add this extra piece of info (popup or not) to the LinkColumns in Django-tables2, because the links to the edit-page, also need to have this information.
Django-tables2 has an accessor, which can be used to access properties in the queryset, but I need to add an extra piece of data, *outside of the queryset*. I have seen that adding extra data to an existing dataset is tricky at best, also, that doesn't feel very clean.

I was wondering if there isn't a simple way to add extra data to the tables or columns class, I have tried looking in the table.meta class as well, but to no avail.

My code is as follows:

TABLES.PY

```
class ArticlegroupTable(tables.Table):

    artg_name = LinkIfAuthorizedColumn(
        'ArticlegroupUpdate',
        args=["popup", A('pk')],
        edit_perm="articles.maintenance",
    )
```

This ofcourse works, but it is adding the "popup" arugument as a *fixed string* as you can see...

```
class ArticlegroupTable(tables.Table):

artg_name = LinkIfAuthorizedColumn(
    'ArticlegroupUpdate',
    args=[A('popup'), A('pk')],
    edit_perm="articles.maintenance",
)
```

This does *not* work, because there isn't a "popup" property in the queryset...

VIEWS.PY

```
    def get_context_data(self, ** kwargs):
    # get context data to be passed to the respective templates
    context = super(ArticlegroupSearch, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data = self.get_queryset()
    table = ArticlegroupTable(data, self.request)
    RequestConfig(self.request, paginate={
        "per_page": 5,
        }).configure(table)
    context.update({'table': table})
    if 'popup' in self.kwargs:
        context.update({'popup': self.kwargs['popup']})
    return context
```

It seems that this is not a very far-fetched scenario (adding a URL parameter to a table/column in tables2), so I was wondering if anyone knows of a simple way to do so.

Thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 2):

If you're after a quick hack, just implement the table's `__init__` method and add the `popup` arg to the `LinkColumn`s dynamically:

```
class ArticlegroupTable(tables.Table):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.pop("popup", False):
            for column in self.base_columns.values():
                if isinstance(column, tables.LinkColumn):
                    column.args.insert(0, "popup")
        super(Table, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # …
```

Then in your view pass in a `popup` argument:

```
def get_context_data(self, ** kwargs):
    # get context data to be passed to the respective templates
    context = super(ArticlegroupSearch, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    data = self.get_queryset()
    popup = self.kwargs.get('popup')
    table = ArticlegroupTable(data, self.request, popup=popup)
    RequestConfig(self.request, paginate={
        "per_page": 5,
        }).configure(table)
    context.update({'table': table, 'popup': popup})
    return context
```

Comment: Thanks Bradley. 
I have two problems with this; The first is that I only need the extra parameter for some columns, not for all. Not all columns have a link with a reverse() function that accepts a popup parameter; The last column is a delete link that shows a confirmation-page in a modal DIV. This confirmation page does not have/need a popup parameter.
Second problem is that the popup value seems to be cached. If I remove the popup keyword from the URL, the value is empty, but tables2 still shows all links with 'popup', until I reload the server.  
Is there a less 'hacky' way?

Comment: My example was to demonstrate how you can tweak columns at run time. There's no baked in functionality that will make what you want to do easy, so in that sense any solution that involves tweaking django-tables2 is going to be hacky. Have you considered using the querystring to indicate the "popup" state?

Comment: Hi Bradley, I have, but doesn't this give me the same problem? Or is there a way to read querystring parameters in tables2 and pass that as a parameter to a specific column?

Comment: Just modify the `Table.__init__` to only affect the columns you want to change…